# What does float->float mean in OCaml?

Tags: ocaml, ml

I have this type, which defines an expression. I know that `*` symbol lets me add pairs, but what is the `->` for?

```
 # type expression = Value of float                   
                | Sum of (expr*expr)     
                | Subtraction of (expr*expr)     
                | Fc1 of ((float->float)*expr)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `->` operator is for function types. `a -> b` means "`a` in, `b` out", so `float -> float` is the type of functions that take a float as their argument and produce a float as their result.

> What about `float -> float -> float`

`->` is right-associative, so `a -> b -> c` is the same as `a -> (b -> c)` meaning a function that takes an `a` and produces another function of type `b -> c`. Functions like this are often used to simulate multi-arguments functions (you can use `f x y` to apply `f` to `x` and then apply the resulting function to `y`, which effectively calls the inner function with two arguments) as an alternative to tuples. This way of simulating multi-argument functions is called currying.

Comment: What about `float -> float -> float` ?